# How to programmatically rename virtual desktop on Cinnamon

Tags: x11, desktop, cinnamon

I'm looking for a way to programmatically create a new desktop and then immediately give it some arbitrary name.

Creating a new desktop is not a problem, but I can't find a way to rename it.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Cinnamon 2.2.16

Comment: So how do you script desktop creation?

Comment: I'm using `wmctrl -n x` with `x` the wanted number of desktops.

Comment: Not a solution for this? Using default Ctrl+Alt+Up and rename is a pain...